# How to indicate different groups of connected points/nodes(2D plane)?

Tags: matlab, networking

I have the following sets of 2D points. Each point represents a node.

```
x=[0 1 1 3 4 4 5];
y=[0 0 1 3 4 5 6];
```

If a point is within 1 unit of distance from another point they are considered neighbors. The following code creates a neighborhood matrix A in which 1 indicates that the corresponding nodes(points) are neighbors.

```
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        if dist(i,j)<=1
            A(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
end
```

However this code does not point out groups of connected nodes. I want the code to indicate the different connected parts of the network separately(the above given 2D space represents a network of nodes where each point is a node). For example it should tell that there are three partitions i.e. 1,2 and 6 are connected;  4 and 5 are connected and 3 and 7 are connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find connected components (part in your terminology) of a graph, you can use a typical graph search such as DFS. The idea is there at least one path between each two node of a component (part). Therefore, by doing DFS from one particular node, you can find all of the nodes which are in the same component. However, Matlab provided a useful function to find all connected components.

Specially for your problem, the solution is first convert your neighborhood matrix to a Graph. Then, because your graph is not directed, you should find weakly connected components.

```
G = graph(A);
c = conncomp(G,'Type','weak');
numberOfComponents = max(c);
```

Also for retrieving elements of ith component, you can use

```
elements = find(c == i);
```